GCP IAM condition
I granted a user as K8S cluster admin with condition that the resource.name.endsWith("non-prod"), however, the condition does not work, the user still cannot maintain the non-prod clusters
Condition on "Kubernetes Engine Admin" role
{
"expression": "resource.name.endsWith("non-prod")",
"title": "Admin access for non-prod cluster",
"description": "Admin access for non-prod cluster."
}
Expected result: users with this IAM role binding can maintain the non-prod clusters.
Actual result: users with this IAM role binding condition cannot manage any non-prod cluster.
